# OpenPanel change the document root for an addon domain?

Tags: symfony, configuration, panel, document-root

How to change the document root for an addon domain?

I have a VPS hosting several websites. I only want to change the document root for one of them, which is actually using the symfony 2, and points to the typical public_html folder. I want to change it in order to point to the the public_html/web/ folder instead.

Seems people is using their hosting control panel software to do so like Cpanel. unfortunately I have openpanel (http://www.openpanel.com/) and the options/capabilities of this latest are more limited. There is a way do so this even manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out that openpanel does not provide that posibility.

So I had to do it manually.

in the following folder:

```
/etc/apache2/openpanel.d
```

your domain (or subdomain -> we will take sub.domain.com as example) will have a specific config file:

```
sub.domain.com.conf
```

open it

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot       /home/user/sites/sub.domain.com/public_html/
   ServerName         sub.domain.com
   <Directory /home/user/sites/sub.domain.com/public_html/>
   AllowOverride      All
   Allow from all
   </Directory>
   Include /etc/apache2/openpanel.d//sub.domain.com.inc/[^.#]*
   Include /etc/apache2/openpanel.d//global.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

change it to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   DocumentRoot       /home/user/sites/sub.domain.com/public_html/web/
   ServerName         sub.domain.com
   <Directory /home/user/sites/sub.domain.com/public_html/web>
   AllowOverride      All
   Allow from all
   </Directory>
   Include /etc/apache2/openpanel.d//sub.domain.com.inc/[^.#]*
   Include /etc/apache2/openpanel.d//global.inc
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that in the line I've added "/web/" in the line 2 and "/web" in the line 4